# How to add Program arguments in to Intellij idea gwt project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add the same Program arguments that have Eclipse Run configuration in to Intellij idea. When I coping them it splits arguments on two lines if there is white space.
If I'm adding:

```
-port 8888
```

Intellij idea splits it to

```
-port
8888
```

And when compiles shows message:

```
A port must be an integer
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"]
```

Comment: Passing arguments into a main method are given as a `String` array. Trying doing `Integer.parseInt(port);` to get an int from  the String. I have never used GWT however, so this is on the basis that the values are controlled by yourself.

Comment: Are you adding them in run configuration?
(Run/Debug Configurations -> GWT Configuration -> "YourConfigName" -> "Dev Mode parameters"). It works fine for me.